# Compress Python objects before saving to cache

Tags: django, caching, memcached, compression

What's the fast method to compress Python objects (list, dictionary, string, etc) before saving them to cache and decompress after read from cache?

I'm using Django and I hope to add compress/decompress support directly in Django's cache backend which makes it available to all my Django apps.

I looked into django/core/cache/backends/memcached.py

```
import cmemcache as memcache

class CacheClass(BaseCache):

    def __init__(self, server, params):
        BaseCache.__init__(self, params)
        self._cache = memcache.Client(server.split(';'))

    def get(self, key, default=None):
        val = self._cache.get(smart_str(key))
        if val is None:
            return default
        return val

    def set(self, key, value, timeout=0):
        self._cache.set(smart_str(key), value, self._get_memcache_timeout(timeout))
```

Looks like pickle/unpickle is done by cmemcache library. I dont know where to put the compress/decompress code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked further into python-memcache's source code.

It already supported compressing values by zlib before sending them to memcached.

```
lv = len(val)
# We should try to compress if min_compress_len > 0 and we could
# import zlib and this string is longer than our min threshold.
if min_compress_len and _supports_compress and lv > min_compress_len:
    comp_val = compress(val)
    # Only retain the result if the compression result is smaller
    # than the original.
    if len(comp_val) < lv:
        flags |= Client._FLAG_COMPRESSED
        val = comp_val

def _set(self, cmd, key, val, time, min_compress_len = 0):
```

Here is Django's implemention for the "set" command in its memcache backend:

```
def set(self, key, value, timeout=0):
    self._cache.set(smart_str(key), value, self._get_memcache_timeout(timeout))
```

Apparently it does not have "min_compress_len" parameter.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly - are you sure you need it? Are your data structures too big just to fit uncompressed in the cache? There is going to be an overhead for compression/decompression, that may void any gains you've made by caching in the first place.

If you really do need compression, then you probably want to use [zlib](http://docs.python.org/library/zlib.html).

If you are going to use zlib, you might want to experiment with the different compression levels available in the `compress` method, to balance CPU time vs compression levels:

> `zlib.compress(string[, level])`
>   Compresses the data in string, returning a string contained compressed data. `level` is an integer from 1 to 9 controlling the level of compression; 1 is fastest and produces the least compression, 9 is slowest and produces the most. The default value is 6. Raises the [`error`](http://docs.python.org/library/zlib.html#zlib.error) exception if any error occurs.

Comment: My server is IO bound and RAM bound, not CPU bound. Current memcached allocation uses 1.3GB of RAM. So compressing the data by 50% saves 650MB RAM or make it possible to store twice more items in the cache.

Comment: thanks, I voted up your answer. But I hope to find a more generic solution which modifies in the cache backend.

Comment: @jack I wonder if your best bet is a custom cache backend, that wraps around memcaches and compresses around setting and decompresses around retrieval - see http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#using-a-custom-cache-backend